# Tasker Volume does not work

Tags: tasker

I use the latest version of tasker.

I created a simple task Category Audio and then Media volume and system volume.

I set both of them to the maximum (15). However, when I run the tasks, the volume does not change. ideas?

FYI I'm using a Samsung SG10 and android 11.

Comment: you have to grant permissions as device administrator app

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found a solution. seem to be a bug in Tasker.

Action 1: Set the Volume.

***Action 2: Add 1 Second Wait***

Now volume changes!

Note: I have not tweaked Wait times, it could be possible it can be optimized.